# How to make my code to generate polytopes more efficient?

Tags: performance-tuning, geometry, code-review

The main purpose of my code is to generate polytopes by starting with a point. With this point, I then apply 3 actions which generates at most 3 others points:

```
pi1[a_, b_, c_] := {a, b, c} - a*cartm[[1]];
pi2[a_, b_, c_] := {a, b, c} - b*cartm[[2]];
pi3[a_, b_, c_] := {a, b, c} - c*cartm[[3]];
picomb[a_, b_, c_] := Prepend[List[pi1[a, b, c], pi2[a, b, c], pi3[a, b, c]], {a, b, c}];
```

where

```
 cartm = {{2, -1, 0}, {-1, 2, -1}, {0, -1, 2}};
```

From now on, I am willing to apply those 3 exact actions on the new list of the 4 possible points. In fact, I want to act those 3 actions on every new list generated until the length of the previous one is equal to the new one generated. But, I only made it possible by using brute force technique:

```
    orb1[list_] := 
  DeleteDuplicates@
   Partition[
    Flatten@Table[
      picomb@picomb[list][[i]], {i, 1, Length@picomb[list]}], 3];
orb2[list_] := 
  With[{liste = orb1[list]}, 
   DeleteDuplicates@
    Partition[Flatten@Table[picomb@liste[[i]], {i, 1, Length@liste}], 
     3]];
orb3[list_] := 
  With[{liste = orb2[list]}, 
   DeleteDuplicates@
    Partition[Flatten@Table[picomb@liste[[i]], {i, 1, Length@liste}], 
     3]];
```

and so on, until the 3 actions no longer affect the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not as elegant as the previous answer, but it does a great job:

```
pi[list_] := list - list[[#]]*cartm[[#]] & /@ {1, 2, 3};

orbit[list_] := 
  Module[{listGraph, listeTemp, i, j}, listGraph = {}; 
   listeTemp = list; 
   For[i = 1, i <= Length[listeTemp], i++, 
    If[MemberQ[listGraph, listeTemp[[i]]], Null, 
     AppendTo[listGraph, listeTemp[[i]]]; 
     listGraph = Partition[Flatten@listGraph, 3]; 
     AppendTo[listeTemp, pi[listeTemp[[i]]]]; 
     listeTemp = Partition[Flatten@listeTemp, 3]]];
   Table[listGraph[[j]][[1]]*w1 + listGraph[[j]][[2]]*w2 + 
     listGraph[[j]][[3]]*w3, {j, 1, Length@listGraph}]];
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you will find this a bit more elegant:

```
ClearAll[F, f];
M = Developer`ToPackedArray[{{2, -1, 0}, {-1, 2, -1}, {0, -1, 2}}];
f[x_?VectorQ] := KroneckerProduct[{1, 1, 1}, x] - x M;
F[list_?MatrixQ] := Union[list, Union @@ (f /@ list)];
DoItAll[a_, b_, c_] := FixedPoint[F, Developer`ToPackedArray[{{a, b, c}}]]
```

Usage example:

```
DoItAll[1, 2, 3] == Union @@ (orb2 @@@ orb2[1, 2, 3])
```

> True

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I really appreciate your time, but it is too complicated for me. Plus, I wished I could have stick to something similar to the original code or use a function such as NestWhileList.

Comment: Amazing simplification of the original code !

Comment: I totally agree with you. His code is way simpler than mine. The point is that I only want to work on the part where it generates new points without having to brute force like it just like I did.

Comment: @LilGreg For your info: `f` is the part that generates the new point. `F` maps `f` over all preexistent points and unites them with the newly generated points. `FixedPoint` is a basically a `NestWhile` that stops when nothing changes any more. So this is essentially what you asked for.